# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded after patching WebSphere

Tags: java, encryption, websphere

Well, this is not a new program and I haven't done any changes with problem parts.
My system admin has just patched the IBM WebSphere Application Server from 8.5.0.1 to 8.5.5.4.
I have encrypted numbers of files in the past. But after the upgrade has completed, I can't decrypt these files any more.
I am sure I am using the same method and key as they are all hard-coded in my program. And I haven't changed any related codes.

Here is the error.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
at com.xxx.framework.core.common.util.CipherUtil.crypt(CipherUtil.java:175)
at com.xxx.framework.core.common.util.CipherUtil.decrypt(CipherUtil.java:102)
at com.xxx.framework.core.common.util.ZipCipherUtil.decryptUnzip(ZipCipherUtil.java:84)
at xxx(xxx.java:2894)
at xxx(xxx.java:748)
at xxx(xxx.java:727)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at yyy(ActionProxy.java:54)
```

I have deleted some parts as there are some sensitive business information
And this is the code

CipherUtil.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class CipherUtil {
    private static String type = "AES";

    private static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    public void encrypt(String srcFile, String destFile, String privateKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        Key key = getKey(privateKey);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(type + "/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mkdirFiles(destFile));

            crypt(fis, fos, cipher);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void decrypt(String srcFile, String destFile, String privateKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        Key key = getKey(privateKey);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(type + "/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mkdirFiles(destFile));

            crypt(fis, fos, cipher);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Key getKey(String secret) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(type);
        kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(secret.getBytes()));
        SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
        return secretKey;
    }

    private static void crypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out, Cipher cipher) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize() * 1000;
        int outputSize = cipher.getOutputSize(blockSize);

        byte[] inBytes = new byte[blockSize];
        byte[] outBytes = new byte[outputSize];

        int inLength = 0;
        boolean more = true;
        while (more) {
            inLength = in.read(inBytes);
            if (inLength == blockSize) {
                int outLength = cipher.update(inBytes, 0, blockSize, outBytes);
                out.write(outBytes, 0, outLength);
            } else {
                more = false;
            }
        }
        if (inLength > 0)
            outBytes = cipher.doFinal(inBytes, 0, inLength);
        else
            outBytes = cipher.doFinal();
        out.write(outBytes);
    }

    public String encryptString(String srcString, String keyString) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Key key = getKey(keyString);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(type + "/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] coded = cipher.doFinal(srcString.getBytes());

        return byteArrayToHexString(coded);
    }   

    public String decryptString(String srcString, String keyString) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Key key = getKey(keyString);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(type + "/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] decoded = cipher.doFinal(hexStringToByteArray(srcString));

        return new String(decoded);
    }


    private String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] raw) 
    {
        if (raw == null) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * raw.length);

        for (final byte b : raw) 
        {
            hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
                .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        if (s == null || (s.length() % 2) == 1)
        {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        final char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        final int len = chars.length;
        final byte [] data = new byte [len / 2];

        for (int i=0; i<len; i+=2) 
        {
           data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit (chars[i], 16) << 4) + Character.digit (chars[i + 1], 16));
        }
        return data;
    }   
}
```

Although I have mentioned "files", this method only treat the files as binary string to encrypt.

As I have DEV and UAT environment to test (DEV=8.5.5.4, UAT=8.5.0.1), I have tried to put the old encrypted files on DEV to the UAT. And they can decrypted under UAT.
Also I have tried to encrypt a new file under DEV and decrypt it, it is ok.

Is there anything I need to call my system admin to do?
I am only a programmer and I am not very skillful in server setup.

P.S. If there is anything to check, I am able to go into the WebSphere admin panel with admin right.
P.S.2. These codes are not written by me. Don't ask me what is the reason of these coding. By the way I have checked the codes and I can't find any issue with these codes, except some security worries but I am not sure.

Comment: Try some charsets: `secret.getBytes("UTF-8")`. This contains some charsets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: I have tried but there is no difference. The new thing I only find today is the file generated encrypted files with 8.5.0.1 and 8.5.5.4 can't be decrypted in the opposite environment. Well I have re-generated the file in both environemnt, checked the md5sum and found they are not match. And seems the binary data is also in a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is your problem or not, but this block:

```
while (more) {
    inLength = in.read(inBytes);
    if (inLength == blockSize) {
        int outLength = cipher.update(inBytes, 0, blockSize, outBytes);
        out.write(outBytes, 0, outLength);
    } else {
        more = false;
    }
}
```

is at least in principle incorrect. The in.read() could theoretically read less than the block length before reaching the end of file. [The EOF condition is that in.read() returns -1.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29) Maybe the update to the operating system has caused the FileInputStream to occasionally interrupt the read? In this case you will for the first time fall into the the inLength > 0 block of your code and try to decrypt a partial block which will definitely give the wrong result.

You can also temporarily disable PKCS5Padding by using NoPadding and see what the output of the encryption is.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But seems this is not the current reason of the problem as the blockSize is always larger than inLength. Also I have checked the read bytes and it is normal on both 8.5.0.1 and 8.5.5.4. In addition I have tried to replace PKCS5Padding with NoPadding, and seems there is no valid output.

Comment: Have you checked that you have read the entire file? Potentially, in.read(inBytes) can return without reading the entire file, that is the case that you will perform a doFinal with incomplete information. The only other thing to check is to output the block using for example DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(inBytes) on the DEV and UAT environment to make sure they are getting the same inputs. Do this also for the keys if you are able. If the inputs are the same and keys are the same and you are getting different outputs the only possibility is the crypto library is malfunctioning.

Comment: Yes I have checked that it really read the entire file in the doFinal. I will do other checking tomorrow.